# Does MariaDB allow a column alias in an ORDER BY clause?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sql-order-by, alias

I am migrating my MySQL database between hosting companies. The old one uses MySQL 5.6.36-82.1 and the new one uses MariaDB (not sure of the version but they say it is the latest)

One of the views has two selects UNIONed together. Each select makes the same column alias of one column which is then used outside of the union as a ORDER BY . The alias is created just before the FROM in each SELECT.

This is working fine in MySQL but the company say they cannot migrate the DB SQL backup to MariaDB as it is complaining that the alias in the ORDER BY clause is a column that doesn't exist.
Is this a known bug of MariaDB. ie you can't use column aliases in ORDER BY?

The code of the view is below in case it helps and it is the `ORDER BY jointmember_sn` that they say it is objecting to.

```
DELIMITER $$

ALTER ALGORITHM =
   TEMPTABLE DEFINER = themam54_sitka @82.71.38.7 SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW member_and_joint_member AS
   (SELECT
      member.member_id AS member_id,
      IFNULL(member.member_title, '') AS member_title,
      (
         CASE
            WHEN (
               member.member_known_as IS NOT NULL
            )
            THEN CONCAT(
               member.member_fn_1,
               ' (',
               member.member_known_as,
               ')'
            )
            ELSE member.member_fn_1
         END
      ) AS member_fn,
      member.member_sn AS member_sn,
      member_1.member_id AS joint_member_id,
      IFNULL(member_1.member_title, '') AS joint_member_title,
      (
         CASE
            WHEN (
               member_1.member_known_as IS NOT NULL
            )
            THEN CONCAT(
               member_1.member_fn_1,
               ' (',
               member_1.member_known_as,
               ')'
            )
            ELSE member_1.member_fn_1
         END
      ) AS joint_member_fn,
      member_1.member_sn AS joint_member_sn
   FROM
      (
         (
            joint_member
            JOIN member
               ON (
                  (
                     joint_member.base_member_id = member.member_id
                  )
               )
         )
         JOIN member member_1
            ON (
               (
                  joint_member.partner_member_id = member_1.member_id
               )
            )
      )
   ORDER BY member_sn)
   UNION
   ALL
   (SELECT
      member_1.member_id AS member_id,
      IFNULL(member_1.member_title, '') AS member_title,
      (
         CASE
            WHEN (
               member_1.member_known_as IS NOT NULL
            )
            THEN CONCAT(
               member_1.member_fn_1,
               ' (',
               member_1.member_known_as,
               ')'
            )
            ELSE member_1.member_fn_1
         END
      ) AS member_fn,
      member_1.member_sn AS member_sn,
      member.member_id AS joint_member_id,
      IFNULL(member.member_title, '') AS joint_member_title,
      (
         CASE
            WHEN (
               member.member_known_as IS NOT NULL
            )
            THEN CONCAT(
               member.member_fn_1,
               ' (',
               member.member_known_as,
               ')'
            )
            ELSE member.member_fn_1
         END
      ) AS joint_member_fn,
      member.member_sn AS joint_member_sn
   FROM
      (
         (
            joint_member
            JOIN member
               ON (
                  (
                     joint_member.base_member_id = member.member_id
                  )
               )
         )
         JOIN member member_1
            ON (
               (
                  joint_member.partner_member_id = member_1.member_id
               )
            )
      )
   ORDER BY jointmember_sn) $$

DELIMITER;
```

Comment: *Each select makes the same column alias of one column* where is that alias? `jointmember_sn` is mentioned only in the last ORDER BY.

Comment: The alias is just before the FROM clause in each select, `member.member_sn AS joint_member_sn`. The first select takes uses the first column of the table joint_member and calls that `jointmember_sn`, the second select is taking the second column but also calling it `jointmember_sn` and then I order by on `jointmember_sn`. So the result is two sets of four columns, husbands and wives followed by the same data again but shown as wives and husbands, even if their surnames are different. Allows me to report which partner goes with which in surname order no matter if you start with husband or wife

Comment: `joint_member_sn` is not the same as `jointmember_sn`

Comment: Ah, just spotted that myself.  That's wrong it should be joint_member_sn, same as the alias. So now I'm puzzled why the view works in MySQL.

Comment: It does not work in MySql either.

Comment: I'm afraid it does, I'm looking at the result of the view right now in SQLyog. Very odd. never mind, that's resolved my original question, MariaDB seem better at spotting errors than MySQL

Comment: Does the `ORDER BY` do anything -- since it is in each side of the `UNION`?